# "Movie not loaded" error when viewing Flash movie in any browser

Tags: adobe-flash

When I view a flash movie that's embedded in a page in FF 23, Safari 7.0.3, or Chrome 37, I see a black screen where the movie should be.  When I right click on the movie, I get a "movie not loaded" error.

I've got Flash 14.0.0.177 installed according to this, and the clouds are moving under the "5. Verify if Flash Player is installed" section: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html

Anybody know how to fix this?  Guessing it's an OS-level thing since the behavior is the same in all browsers.

EDIT:

Here is an example page where this occurs:

http://time.com/3265308/ikea-catalog-2015

Comment: sorry, where is your movie coming from ? your hard drive or outside source. You say embedded? where is it embedded? FF should be at ver 32.

Comment: Give us a web site example with embedded movie to cross check.

Comment: If you are using Chrome and that doesn't work, the problem is most likely due to the website as Chrome uses its own builtin Flash Player.

Comment: Here's an example: http://time.com/3265308/ikea-catalog-2015/